# Trouble receiving push notifications in iOS10 and iOS9

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, swift3

Trying to set up push notification for iOS10. had it working previously for versions below 10.
Read through some guides my setup is like so:

```
// Register for the defined notifications

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in

                if error == nil {
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            }

        } else {

            // Fallback on earlier versions

            let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: [autoCancelCategory])
            UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        }
```

This is called on login ^ in one of my view controllers.

And now in `AppDelegate`, it conforms to `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`, I have these methods:

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    print("Got a push!")
}


@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("Got a push!")
}
```

And I also have:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

    let settings = UserDefaults.standard
    settings.setValue(deviceToken, forKey: "deviceToken")
}
```

The device token is uploaded to the server as `Data`, and this has worked fine for previous versions.
I have checked that the token on the server matches the one on the phone.
I have enabled push notifications for all targets in `Capabilities`, I have also ticked `Add the push Notifications entitlement to your entitlements file`.
Not receiving anything at all though on the  push.
Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here? Any pointers would be really appreciated! 
Thanks!

EDIT: I have also noticed that the push notifications are not working in iOS9.

Comment: It may be OS problem. Please try by restarting a device. https://twitter.com/yogye7/status/781340933228945408

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to answer this, maybe it will be useful for other. My token was wrong. The encoding has changed with recent updates. I did actually search all over stack overflow for this and it was to my understanding that I had to convert the `Data` to a `String` using the `base64string`. However I noticed this string had a few odd characters in it such as `\`. I eventually ended up making a `Data` extension:

```
extension Data {

    func hexString() -> String {
        return self.reduce("") { string, byte in
            string + String(format: "%02X", byte)
        }
    }

}
```

This converts the `Data` to the correct format. So if this is how you do your conversion, plus all the entitlements are set, you remember to add the new methods:

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    print("Got a push!")
}


@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("Got a push!")
}
```

and set the delegate object in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` everything should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked that Build Settings > Code Signing Entitlements has a reference to entitlements file? [AppName].entitlements.

And that the entitlements file contains the correct info:

(key: APS Environment, value: development)

Other than that, you can try regenerating push certificates. We had to create new certificates to get it to work in production after IOS 10 upgrade (but not in sandbox environment).

Comment: Checked the Build Settings > Code Signing Entitlements and there doesn't seem to be a problem there.

Comment: @Kex had a same problem with number of apps at our company. Please also check  Build Settings > Capabilities and make sure "Notifications" are Switched ON.

Answer (score 2):

Just noticed that you're registering the delegate later than `application(_:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` or `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` methods are called.

Perhaps this is why your delegate methods are not being hit?

See the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate):

> Important
>
> You must assign your delegate object to the UNUserNotificationCenter object no later before your app finishes launching. For example, in an iOS app, you must assign it in the application(*:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) or application(*:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) method.

Comment: Really nice spot! I'll give it a shot when I get back home and let you know the results.

Comment: moved `let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current() ; center.delegate = self` to `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool` and still nothing coming through

Comment: I've got mine as: 

`if #available(iOS 10.0, *)  { 
UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().delegate = self
}`

Comment: you're not on Swift 3 yet I assume?

Comment: You're right. There's something else stopping you from getting those notifications, though defining the delegate in the correct place is at least a start.

Comment: Have you tried to receive the notifications in different states? i.e. app is in the foreground, app is in the background, app is killed.